# Using @Configurable domain object properties to assign a specific behaviour based on data

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-aop

I have a domain object which looks like this.
i need to use the data fetched from the database ("type" in this example) to fetch and inject the correct type of service.

I get this output which means that the DB data are not set during the call :

```
entity is a bean postconstruct: PocProduct [id=null, type=null, productName=null].. attching behavior!
```

I get the same resilt when I try with the initializing Bean.
What is the correct way to configure this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AAA_POC_PROD")
@Configurable(dependencyCheck = true)
@Scope("prototype")
public class PocProduct implements Serializable, InitializingBean {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1136936011238094989L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String productName;

    @Transient
    private Behaviour behaviour;

    @Transient
    @Autowired
    private BehaviourFactory behaviourFactory;
    //getters and setters

    @PostConstruct
    public void attachBehavior() {
        System.out.println("entity is a bean postconstruct: " + this + ".. attching behavior!");
        //Need to call this : depends on type which is fetched from DB
       // this.behaviour = behaviourFactory.getTypeBasedBehaviour(type);
    }


}
```

Comment: Depending on your JPA version `@PostConstruct` is also being called by that instead of Spring. But do you really need a heavy solution like that? Are the types static? How is the `BehaviourFactory` created and managed by Spring? Are the different `Behaviour ` instances also Spring managed?

Comment: I would say: spring beans and persistence entities should not be merged like that. I would say what you are looking for is `@PostLoad`

Comment: @M. Deinum .The Spring InitializingBean: afterPropertiesSet() also gets null values. The types ate static. the bahviourfactory is a singleton which returns a behaviour based on the type of object.

Comment: @trejekid it works and sees the data: but i need a solution in spring if possible

Comment: IMHO you don't need a spring been. If the types are static, make the `BehaviorFactory` a factory with a static method which return the correct `Behavior` and create a `@PostLoad` method. That way you don't need to have a full blown aspectj solution. But only rely on JPA. Or create a custom type for your `Behavior` field which sets the correct one upon loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configurable beans are initialized by Spring after or before construction, depending on the value of the `@Configurable.preConstruction` attribute. When loading an entity from a database this means the following sequence of events:

1. The JPA provider creates the entity by invoking it's constructor via reflection
2. While the constructor executes, `spring-aspects`' `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect` intercepts the constructor execution and, before (or after) the constructor executes, Spring will configure this newly created object by executing any bean configuration you have in your spring context, including autowiring of properties.
3. The JPA provider will receive this object already configured by Spring and will start populating its persistent properties with data fetched from the DB.
4. Optionally, if you set up `@PostLoad` methods, the JPA provider will invoke these methods so that your entities have a chance to do work after the entity is fully populated by data from the DB.

From what I see you're trying to do, this 4th step is where you should put your custom behavior logic, assuming everything else is working properly.